# Can Express.js render different routes on same 'res' object?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Can I have the following config in route/index.js ?

```
exports.PageA = function(req, res) {
...
...
    if(req.method == 'GET') {
        if (condition1) {
            //PageA has 2 .js files
            res.render('PageA', { title: 'A', layout: false});
        }
        else {
            //PageB has 2 + 2 .js files
            res.render('PageB', { title: 'B', layout: false});
        }
    }
    else {
        res.render('PageC', { title: 'B', layout:'some_other_layout' });
    }
};
```

Case: mywebsite.com/PageA renders correctly when condition1 passes (with all scripts loaded and executed correctly)

Issue : But when condition1 fails, I get PageB rendered, javascripts in PageB.ejs are rendered but not executed, say, on $document.Ready().
Strangely if I 'Refresh' the already rendered PageB in browser, javascripts are then executed correctly.

As a piece of info: I use defer="defer" tag in all "<  script  >..."

What am I missing here?

Comment: Thanks @Vadim Baryshev, It seems it was JQueryMobile that was creating nuisance.
This is known and expected behavior of JQMobile [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564241/jquery-mobile-page-loses-javascript-file)

Comment: As a solution, I will proceed by having +2 scripts content put inside <script></script> within <div data-role="content"> of PageB

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is entirely on the client side. Attribute "defer" supported only in Internet Explorer and Firefox at this moment. I think your problem is that the scripts are loaded in the wrong sequence. Check your browser console for errors. When you re-load a page, the scripts are loaded from the browser cache. It's faster. Therefore, the error may not appear in this situation.